# Windows update apparently deleted Android SDK files from Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I just restarted my Windows 10 machine to install some updates, and afterward I started getting this error in Visual Studio:

```
Error       Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. 
Please install it or set Android SDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu.            0
```

Which I thought was weird, since I'd never run into any issues with my Android SDK before. So I went to Tools->Android to open the SDK manager, but all the options were grayed out and not selectable. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Grayed-out Android Tools]

So I did a little research, and [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69603/visual-studio-2015-xamarin-forms-tools-android-all-grayed) told me to manually start my SDK manager with the .exe file. So I searched my files for the SDK manager, but when I clicked to open it, I got this error message:

```
The item that this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved.
Would you like to remove this shortcut?
```

And I got the same error for the Uninstall Android SDK Tools and AVD Manager shortcuts. So it seems that all my Android SDK files were for some reason deleted during my Windows updates.

Then I noticed that under Visual Studio Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android, the "Android SDK Location" was empty. Screenshot:

[image: Android SDK Location]

So then I downloaded Android Studio from the [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html), found the location to the .exe file, and then copy-and-pasted the path into the "Android SDK Location" field, and clicked "OK". But the field wasn't saved. No matter what I do, when I open Options, the "Android SDK Location" field is always empty.

I have no idea how to proceed. Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I ran Visual Studio Installer, clicked Modify, and under "Individual Components", it tells me that I already have the latest Android SDK setup (API level 25) installed. Do I need to install something other than that? Screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Comment: What about modify visual studio using VS installer ?

Comment: I didn't know that could be done. How do I do that on a Visual Studio that's already installed?

Comment: Type Visual Studio Installer in your search bar, run the installer... then VS installer will load, then select Repair on dropdown on your selected VS version

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga It took a while, but repairing it with Visual Studio Installer fixed the problem. Thanks! If you add that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Good news, yes i wil add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to Update Visual studio from Visual studio Installer

When you Load Visual Studio Installer, select repair option...

it will fix all issues...

Answer (score 1):

First, `Android SDK Location` path is `Android SDK` path not `.exe file` path.
Second, check the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` which is default path to store `Android SDK` by Visual Studio to see whether it exists. In my computer like this: [image]

If it doesn't exists, it maybe have been deleted by your computer update process.
Why the "Android SDK Location" field is always empty is because the path is wrong.

You can also get `Android SDK` path with the Android Studio which you have downloaded:

Android Stuido -> File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK, then copy-and-pasted the `Android SDK Location` path to Visual Studio. Find it like this in Android Studio:[image]